# Unable to import required dependencies after pandas update

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conda, spyder

I needed to update pandas to version 1.1 for functionality that was not available in the version that I was using.
I opened the command line to run as administrator (tried without running as administrator and did not have write permissions to current environment) and ran `conda update pandas`.
Now when I run the same code as before (using Spyder, if that matters) I get the following:

`Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:`

Numpy is installed on my computer and the code was running fine before this. What should I look for to determine the problem/fix this?

Comment: Try updating numpy with conda

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Updating Spyder seemed to fix things, but also uninstalled/reinstalled Anaconda before trying that.